# Calculating $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x^{2})dx$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I am supposed, in an  exercise, to calculate the above integral by integrating $f(z) = e^{-z^{2}}$ on the following countor: [image]

I began by separating the path $\gamma$ into three paths (obvious from the picture), and parametrizing each as follows:

$\gamma_{1} : [0, R] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $\gamma_{1}(t) = t$

$\gamma_{2} : [0, \frac{\pi}{4}] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $\gamma_{2}(t) = Re^{it}$

$\gamma_{3} : [0, \frac{\sqrt{2}R}{2}] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $\gamma_{3}^{-}(t) = t + it$ (with reverse orientation).

Then we can say that $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz = \displaystyle\int_{\gamma_{1}} f(z) dz + \displaystyle\int_{\gamma_{2}} f(z) dz - \displaystyle\int_{\gamma_{3}^{-}} f(z) dz = 0$ since the path is closed.

Now $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma_{1}} f(z) dz = \displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{R} e^{-t^{2}} dt$. We also get $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma_{3}^{-}} f(z) dz = -(i + 1) \displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{2}R}{2}}e^{-2it^{2}} dt$. After playing around with sine and cosine a bunch to evaluate that last integral, I get:

$$0 = \int\limits_{0}^{R} e^{-t^{2}} dt + \int\limits_{\gamma_{2}} f(z) dz - \frac{i + 1}{\sqrt{2}} \int\limits_{0}^{R} \cos(u^{2}) du + \frac{i - 1}{\sqrt{2}} \int\limits_{0}^{R} \sin(u^{2}) du$$

I could not evaluate the integral along the second path, but I thought it might tend to 0 as $R \rightarrow \infty$. Then taking limits and equating real parts we get

$$\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi}}{2} = \displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \sin(u^{2}) du + \displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \cos(u^{2}) du$$

If I could argue that the integrals are equal, I would have my result.. But how do I?

So I need to justify two things: why the integral along $\gamma_{2}$ tends to zero and why are the last two integrals equal.

Comment: Just as a [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105107/prove-int-0-infty-sin-x2-dx-converges/105148#105148)

$$\int\limits_0^\infty  {\sin \left( {a{x^2}} \right)\cos \left( {2bx} \right)dx}  = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{8a}}} \left( {\cos \frac{{{b^2}}}{a} - \sin \frac{{{b^2}}}{a}} \right)$$

$$\int\limits_0^\infty  {\cos \left( {a{x^2}} \right)\cos \left( {2bx} \right)dx}  = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{8a}}} \left( {\cos \frac{{{b^2}}}{a} + \sin \frac{{{b^2}}}{a}} \right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parametrisation of the third integral is rather complicated. Why not just write $\gamma_3:[0,R]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $t\mapsto -e^{\pi i/4}t$. Then the integral becomes
$$
\int_R^0 e^{-e^{\pi i/2}t^2}e^{\pi i/4}dt = \int_R^0 e^{-it^2}e^{\pi i/4}dt =
e^{\pi i/4} \int_R^0 \cos t^2 - i \sin t^2 dt.
$$
I am sure you can take it from there.

As for bounding the integral $\int_{\gamma_2}e^{-z^2}dz$, the length of the contour grows linearly with $R$. How fast does the maximum of the integrand decay? It's the standard approach, using the fact that
$$
\left|\int_\gamma f(z) dz\right|\leq \sup\{|f(z)|: z \in \text{ image of }\gamma\}\cdot \text{length of }\gamma.
$$

Comment: Just use your inequality cannot solve the problem!

Comment: I think the best way to obtain what you want is to use the Lebesgue dominated theorem: as R tends to infinity, the integrand tends to 0 and is less than a constant which is integrable on a finite interval.

Comment: Sorry, not a constant, but still a integrable function on the closed interval.

Comment: Old, but still: I'm surprised the OP accepted this as an answer. Your approach does not work here unfortunately. I'm afraid you need to properly estimate this integral (which shouldn't be too difficult though).

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^R e^{-t^2}dt= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}+o(1). \tag{1}$$

$$t\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right] \implies \operatorname{Re}(Re^{it})\ge \frac{R}{\sqrt{2}} \implies \left|\int_{\gamma_2}e^{-z^2}dz\right|\le R\frac{\pi}{4}e^{-R^{\,2}/2}\to0 \tag{2}$$

$$\alpha=\int_0^M e^{it^2}dt \implies \int_0^M \sin(t^2)dt=\frac{\alpha+\overline{\alpha}}{2}.  \tag{3}$$

Try using these deductions for $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma_3$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

An easy  way to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x^{2})dx$

$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{a}}$$ Now replace $a\rightarrow ia$

$$ \int\limits_0^\infty \cos \left( {a{x^2}}\right)dx-i \int\limits_0^\infty \sin \left( {a{x^2}}\right)dx= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{i}} $$ But

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} $$ So

$$ \int\limits_0^\infty \cos \left( {a{x^2}}\right)dx=\int\limits_0^\infty \sin \left( {a{x^2}}\right)dx= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{2a}} $$