# Prove the existence of $t_{0}$ such that $\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx+\sin{t}>0 $ for all $t\geq t_{0}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

I am trying to prove the existence of $t_{0}$ such that
$$\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx+\sin{t}>0 $$ 
for all $t\geq t_{0}$.

Numerical experiments shows this (see the figure).
[image]

The first thing that may come to mind is to show the existence of 
$t_{0}$ such that 
$$\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx>1 $$
when $t\geq t_{0}$

Comment: sin(t) = the integral from 0 to t of -cos(t) from 0 to t , then combine the 2 integrals .

Comment: Nonsense ,sin(0)=0

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I was just about to correct my comment. But how does that simplify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full (improper Riemann) integral on the half line is well known, see [Proof of $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171970/proof-of-int-0-infty-frac-sin-x-sqrtxdx-sqrt-frac-pi2) . (A very related term to google : Fresnel integral.) The definition of having a finite limit as $t\to\infty$ immediately gives the existence of some $t_0>0$ such that if $t>t_0$,

$$\left| \int_0^t \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x}\ dx - \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \right| < 0.1. $$

As $\sqrt{\pi/2} > 1.2$, $\int_0^t \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x}\ dx > 1.1 > 1$ for $t>t_0$, as required.

Comment: Just brilliant...

Comment: @Medo you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $t>\pi$. Then

$$\left|\int_{5\pi}^{t}\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx\right|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{5\pi}}
\left|\int_{5\pi}^{t}\sin{x}dx\right|
\leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{5\pi}}=0.5046265$$

Using matlab,
$$\int_{0}^{5\pi}\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx=1.5048853$$

Therefore, if $t>\pi$  then
$\int_{5\pi}^{t}\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx>1$.

Now, can it be done analytically ?