# Historical context: The Fresnel integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

The evaluation of the Fresnel integrals has been done a plethora of 
times both on this site, and numerous other places. The two main ways of 
evalutating these integrals has either been with some algebraic manipulations. 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(x^2)\mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{t}}\mathrm{d}t
=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-tx^2}\sin{t} \, \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}t
=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^4}
=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}
$$
Where it was amongst other things used that 
$1/\sqrt{t} = \pi^{-1}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-tx^2}\mathrm{d}x$ 
and $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\alpha t}\sin \beta t \mathrm{d}t
= \beta/(\alpha^2 + \beta^2)$. Or for an example http://www.jstor.org/stable/2320230 , http://www.math.binghamton.edu/loya/papers/LoyaMathMag.pdf

Another path to take is complex analysis usually using 
path in the figure below

[image: Wikipedia]

I have seen several proofs using the indented path, but the sources are few. 
For a proof se p.32 [here](http://itcanbeshown.com/integrals/An%20Engineers%20Guide%20to%20Complex%20Integration.pdf) or for a proof on stack.exchange see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251083/some-way-to-integrate-sinx2).
My question is asking for refferences for these methods to evaluate the Fresnel integrals and in particular using complex analysis.

*What are the earliest occurrences of using complex analysis to evaluate the Fresnel integrals?*