# Fresnel Approximation of $\delta$ Function

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, dirac-delta, fresnel-integrals

According to the [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-Distribution#Beispiele_f.C3.BCr_Dirac-Folgen), the $\delta$ distribution can be approximated by sequences of integrable functions $\delta_k$ satisfying

1. $\delta_k(x) \geq 0$
2. $\int_{\mathbb R} \delta_k(x) \mathrm dx = 1$
3. $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb R \setminus B_\varepsilon(0)} \delta_k(x) \mathrm dx = 0$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$,

called Dirac sequences.

One example given is the Fresnel representation
$$
\delta_\varepsilon(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{i \pi \varepsilon}} \exp\left(\frac{i x^2}{\varepsilon}\right) ,
$$
where $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \delta_\varepsilon = \delta$.

My questions are

- These are complex functions, so 1. cannot be satisfied. How does it still qualify as a Dirac sequence?
- To check 2. I tried to calculate the Integral
  $$
  I := \int_{\mathbb R} e^{i x^2} \mathrm dx
  $$
  and found
  $$
  I^2
  = \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{\mathbb R} e^{i (x^2 + y^2)} \mathrm dx \mathrm dy
  = 2 \pi \int_0^\infty \rho e^{i \rho^2} \mathrm d\rho
  = 2 \pi \cdot \left. \frac{1}{2 i} e^{i \rho^2} \right|_0^\infty
  = i \pi - \lim_{R \to \infty} i e^{i R^2} ,
  $$
  which does not converge.
  However, my intuition as well as [wolfram|alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Int%5Be%5E(i+*+x%5E2),+x,+-inf,+inf%5D) tell me that $I$ does converge. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Rewrite $i\pi-ie^{iR^2}$ as $\displaystyle\lim_{a\to0^{+}}\left(i\pi-ie^{(i-a)R^2}\right)$

Comment: @Messney, how does this help me? The limits cannot be switched.

Comment: How do you know that the limits cannot be switched? Try it, and compare your answer with Wolfram's.

Comment: @Messney, the fact that you found some arbitrary way to make it look like the right result does not make your method correct. (You can even ask [wolfram|alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Int%5Br+*+e%5E(i+*+r%5E2),+r,+0,+inf%5D) about that). My error is not in evaluating the final integral. It has to be in transforming the coordinates, but I cannot see why.

Answer (score 1):

The integral
\begin{align}
I&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{i\pi\varepsilon}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ix^2/\varepsilon}dx\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{i\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{iy^2}dy
\end{align}
can be calculated using several method. With $e^{iy^2}=\cos y^2+i\sin y^2$, see for example the numerous answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187729/evaluating-int-0-infty-sin-x2-dx-with-real-methods) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848018/find-int-0-infty-sin-x2-dx)
\begin{align}
I&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{i\pi}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}\left( 1+i \right)\\
&=1
\end{align}