# $ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin(x^2)\cos2\alpha x \, \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, substitution

> How to compute
> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin(x^2)\cos2\alpha x\,\mathrm{d}x
> $$

The integrating by parts does not work. Write
$$
I(\alpha)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin(x^2)\cos2\alpha x\,\mathrm{d}x,
$$
then
$$
I'(\alpha)=-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}2x\sin(x^2)\sin2\alpha x\,\mathrm{d}x.
$$

I do not kwow how to go on. Appreciate any help!

Comment: @Falcon Probably you should write square$^2$ before $x$ :)

Comment: Use $\sin(x^2)\cos(2ax)=\frac 12 (\sin (x^2+2ax)+\sin(x^2-2ax))$. Then $\sin (x^2+2ax)=\sin((x+a)^2-a^2)=\sin((x+a)^2)\cos a^2-\cos((x+a)^2)\sin a^2$. Then use the known fact that $\sin(x^2)$ integral on $(-\infty, \infty)$ is computable...

Comment: After @Yuval 's  hint, you can use: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062974/integral-of-sinx2-from-0-to-infinity?noredirect=1

Comment: Same approach as mine. I wrote the full proof in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

First, let's notice that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin}\left( x^2 \right) \cos 2ax\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin}\left( x^2+2ax \right) +\sin \left( x^2-2ax \right) \,dx
$$
For the first integral, substitute $u=x+a$, we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin}\left( x^2+2ax \right) \,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin}\left( u^2-a^2 \right) \,du = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin}\left( u^2 \right) \cos a^2-\cos \left( u^2 \right) \sin a^2\,du
$$
And a similar process works for the second integral. Finally,
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin}\left( x^2 \right) \cos 2ax&=\cos a^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin}\left( u^2 \right) \,du-\sin a^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos}\left( u^2 \right) \,du\\&\overset{(1)}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left( \cos a^2-\sin a^2 \right)\end{aligned}
$$
<sub>[Proof of (1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190293/752069)</sub>

Comment: Alternatively, $\sqrt{\pi}\cos(\alpha^2+\pi/4)$.