# Help on contour integral on another answer on this site

Tags: proof-explanation, contour-integration

Do you mind expanding on the part along the diagonal in the first answer by Robjohn to this question [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251083/some-way-to-integrate-sinx2)? Particularly how to achieve (3).

I am trying use a parameterization for $z=xe^{i \pi/4}$ for x from $0$ to R and I am not getting the correct result.

$$\int_{diagonal}e^{-z^2}=\int_0^R e^{-(xe^{i \pi/4})^2}e^{i\pi/4}dx=\int_0^R e^{-x^2e^{i \pi/2}}e^{i\pi/4}dx$$

Comment: $e^{i\pi/2}=i$ and the integral is from $Re^{i\pi/4}$ to 0 so you have to change the sign?

Comment: Oh you might be right. Let me take a look at that in a few. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thank you. I see it now. I appreciate the help.

Comment: One of you should post that as an answer so that the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Comment: Yes, please post that Bob or let me know if you want me to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parametrize the segment from $0$ to $R e^{i\pi / 4}$ by:
$$\gamma :[0,R]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}, t\mapsto te^{i(\pi/4)}.$$
Since you want to integrate from $Re^{i\pi/4}$ to $0$ and not from $0$ to $Re^{i\pi/4}$, you have to switch the orientation of this curve, with the result that the integral changes sign, so the value of the integral you're looking for is
$$-\int_\gamma e^{-z^2}dz= -\int_0 ^ R e^{-\gamma(t)^2}\gamma'(t)dt = -\int_0 ^{R} e^{-(te^{i\pi/4})^2}e^{i\pi/4}dt=\\-e^{i\pi/4}\int_0 ^{R} e^{-t^2e^{i\pi/2}}dt=-e^{i\pi/4}\int_0 ^{R} e^{-it^2}dt,$$
where we used the well known fact that $e^{i\pi/2}=i.$ Now, letting $R\rightarrow\infty$ you get the result claimed in the linked answer.

Comment: Thanks Bob :) appreciate it.