# $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f'(t) = 0 \impliedby \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f(t)=c $ is not true!

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

Suppose $f(t)$ is continuously differentiable and $c$ is a finite constant. We know that
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f(t)=c \implies\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f'(t) = 0   \quad \text{is NOT true!}.
\end{equation}

According to Barbalat's Lemma, this is true if $f'(t)$ is uniformly continuous. But can anyone give me a counterexample showing that $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f(t)=c$ NOT implying $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f'(t) = 0 $?

Comment: If $f$ has no derivative then the first limit does not even exist. Please provide some more context and hypotheses. Please do give us your views on the problem as well.

Comment: @BillO'Haran Please see the edit. You are right, but you can think further, considering that $f(t)$ is differentiable. However, i am sorry for missing this condition.

Comment: Even if $f$ is differentiable, bounded, strictly increasing function, 
we can not conclude that $\lim_{t\to \infty} f'(t) = 0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I take that $f'$ should exist. An interesting example is if:

$$f(x) = \int_0^x \sin(t^2) \mathrm dt$$

Then: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \frac 1 2 \sqrt{\frac \pi 2}$$

but: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \sin(x^2)$$

which doesn't exist.

Comment: +1 If the limit of $f'$ exists, though, then it is $0$

Comment: Why is the limit $1/2 *\sqrt{\pi/2}$?

Comment: @winston Well, $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \int_0^\infty \sin (t^2) \mathrm dt$. There are many, many ways to then evaluate this. You can find some [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187729/evaluating-int-0-infty-sin-x2-dx-with-real-methods) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251083/some-way-to-integrate-sinx2). If you are just interested in showing that the integral converges, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105107/prove-int-0-infty-sin-x2-dx-converges) will be more of interest.

Comment: @GeorgeCoote Does this imply that $\sin(x^2)$ is not uniformly continuous?

Comment: @winston: you have guessed correctly that $\sin x^2$ is not uniformly continuous. Why? Because $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(t)=\frac{\sin t^2}{t}.$$
Derivative $[t \cos(t^2)\cdot 2t-\sin(t^2)]/[t^2]$ is $2 \cos(t^2)$ plus something going to zero.

Answer (score -1):

Just adding another counterexample here that isn't using trigonometric functions. It is conceptually very simple. Imagine a smoothened staircase where each step is equally steep but the height of each step is half the size of the one before it. The height converges to a limit but no matter how far you go there are still steep steps so the derivative can't go to 0. Now let's create that staircase:

Take the spike-looking function $\delta$ such that $\delta(x) = \max(0,1-|x|)$. This is a continuous function. Note that its integral over the real line is 1.

Now define $f(x)$ to be a function with such spikes at each natural number, but with the spike at $n$ squeezed horizontally by a factor of $2^n$. That is,

$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \delta(2^n(x-n))$.

Its integral $g$ would have
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = g(0) + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + \cdots = g(0) + 1$$
but
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$$ does not exist.