# How to ensure when the derivative approaches zero, the integral approaches a constant?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I asked a very similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3045037/lim-limits-t-to-infty-ft-0-impliedby-lim-limits-t-to-infty-ft). But now this is different. Suppose $f(t)$ is differentiable and $c$ is a finite constant, then the following statement looks correct, but in fact it is not: 
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f'(t) = 0 \implies \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f(t)=c 
\end{equation}
A counter-example is $f(t)=\ln(t)$. Now the question is, what condition should be used for the above statement to be true?

Comment: The inverse implication is always true: $$
\begin{equation}
 \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f(t)=c\implies  \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f'(t) = 0 
\end{equation}$$
Thus, we find that $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f'(t) = 0 $ is a necessary condition for the function being convergent at $x\to\infty$. I think that what you're actually looking for is a statement $A$ so that $$\left(
\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f'(t) = 0\right) \land A \implies  \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f'(t) = 0 $$ is true, but so that the formula $$ A \implies  \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f'(t) = 0 $$ doesn't hold in general.

Comment: The inverse implication is NOT true. See the link in my question.

Answer (score 3):

An equivalent condition is that
$$
\int_a^\infty f'(t)\,dt
$$
converges as an improper Riemann integral for some $a\in\Bbb R$. This happens for instance if $|f'(x)|\le C\,x^{-p}$ for some $C\ge0$ and $p>1$.

Comment: Is there any proof of your result?

Comment: $$f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^xf'(t)\,dt,\quad x>a.$$

Comment: True if $f'$ is Riemann integrable on bounded intervals.

Comment: Does it mean that $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f'(t)=0$ does not make any difference to the condition? Doesn't it somehow relax your condition in some way?

Comment: If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ exists, it must be $0$. But it may happen that the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could potentially change your statement so that it is true is to assert that the function is bounded asymptotically (as $t \rightarrow \infty$).

If $\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty} f'(t) = 0$ and $\exists n,M$ such that $\forall t > n, |f(t)| \le M$, then $\exists c$ such that $\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty} f(t) = c$

I don't have a proof of this currently, but I believe it should be true, and in fact I believe that this also works in reverse. I will provide a proof if I can come up with one.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways for a differentiable (and hence, continuous) function $f(t)$ to satisfy $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t) = c$:

(1) $f(t) = c$; i.e., is a constant function

(2) $f(t)$ has a horizontal asymptote $y=c$ in the positive x-direction.

Hence, restrict $f(t)$ to be either of these two function types and your original assertion $\lim_{t \to \infty} f'(t) \Rightarrow \lim_{t \to \infty} f(t)$ will be true.