# Give an example of $f$ that is $C^\infty$, $\int_0^\infty f(t)dt$ converges but $f$ does not converge.

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Today, my teacher asked about a real function that was integrable, but such that $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to \infty}f(t)\neq 0$ ($f$ need not have a limit).

It's easy to forge an example: a function that has tightening spikes each with areas $1/n^2$ does the trick.

> He then asked for a real $C^\infty$ function that was integrable, but such that $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to \infty}f(t)\neq 0$ ($f$ need not have a limit).

One heuristic argument is to take the previous function and "smoothen" the spikes. However, he referred to a nicer function that can be defined explicitely.

Do you have an idea ? I've looked for something involving $\sin,\cos,\tan$

Comment: Are you familiar with standard bump functions? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function

Comment: @SamDeHority Yes, what do you plan on doing with them ?

Comment: Does "integrable" refer to Riemann or Lebesgue?

Comment: @DanielFischer Riemann I guess ($\int_0^\infty f(t)$ converges)

Comment: In that case, cnick's answer gives an explicit example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not something like $f(x) = \sin(x^2)$?  It has to oscillate faster as you go towards infinity so that it adds/subtracts less and less area each time in order for the integral to converge.

Comment: Right. You should add this reference in your answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279540/how-to-show-that-int-0-infty-sinx2-dx-converges?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Try to construct "smooth mountains" by using the Cauchy function

$$h:x\mapsto \begin{cases}
e^{-\frac{1}{x}} &\text{if }x>0\\
0&\text{if }x\leq 0
\end{cases}$$

which is very useful for constructing $C^\infty$ functions with that kind of properties.