# Proving Abel-Dirichlet's test for convergence of improper integrals using Integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I'm struggling with the following calculus question.

Let there be two functions $f,g : [a, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ such that:

1. $g$ is monotonic, differentiable and has a limit at zero
2. $f$ is continuous such that $$\int_a^\infty f(x)dx < M \in \mathbb R$$

Prove that integral $$\int_a^{\infty} f(x)g(x)dx$$ converges.

While I do know how to prove the theorem using the Second Mean Value Theorem, I've got no idea how to prove it using integration by parts. How can this be done?

Any hints or leads will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

I assume you mean that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$.

Let $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$. Then, using the [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Properties)
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm{d}F(x)\\
&=\lim_{b\to\infty}g(b)F(b)-g(a)F(a)-\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_a^bF(x)\,\mathrm{d}g(x)\\
&=0-0-\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_a^bF(x)\,\mathrm{d}g(x)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Since $|F(x)|\le M$ and $g'$ doesn't change signs
$$
\left|\int_a^bF(x)\,\mathrm{d}g(x)\right|\le M|g(a)-g(b)|\tag{2}
$$
Thus,
$$
\left|\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right|\le M|g(a)|\tag{3}
$$

---

**Addition from Comments**

It was asked in a comment how we know that the limit in $(1)$ exists, since $(3)$ actually shows only that the integral is bounded in $b$. Using $(1)$, we need to show that
$$
\lim\limits_{b\to\infty}\int_a^bF(x)\,\mathrm{d}g(x)\tag{4}
$$
exists. The limit in $(4)$ exists because
$$
\left|\int_{b_1}^{b_2}F(x)\,\mathrm{d}g(x)\right|\le M|g(b_1)|\tag{5}
$$
and $\lim\limits_{b_1\to\infty}g(b_1)=0$.

Comment: Why does the limit $\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ exist?

Comment: Integration by parts: $\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=F(b)g(b)-F(a)g(a)-\int_a^bF(x)g'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $\lim\limits_{b\to\infty}F(b)g(b)=0$ and $\left|\int_{b_1}^{b_2}F(x)g'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right|\le M|g(b_1)|$.

Comment: Sorry to insist, but it seems to me that you are just proving that $\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\,dx$ is bounded.

Comment: No, I am showing that the limit exists. There are three parts on the right hand side: $$\tag*{}$$ 1. $$\lim_{b\to\infty}F(b)g(b)=0$$ 2. $$\lim\limits_{b\to\infty}F(a)g(a)=F(a)g(a)=0$$ 3. $$\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_a^bF(x)g'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ which exists because $$\left|\int_{b_1}^{b_2}F(x)g'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right|\le M|g(b_1)|$$

Comment: Now it's fine +1 ;)

Comment: Regarding the last line: Why do you let the lower bound go to $\infty$? Has it something to do with Cauchy? Didn't you show with $(2)$ and $(3)$ that the limit exists by showing it is bounded?

Comment: @philmcole: The definition of a Cauchy sequence talks about $|a_k-a_n|$ going to $0$ as $k$ and $n$ go to $\infty$. This is the same thing; we're showing the integral converges by showing $$\left|\int_a^{b_2}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_a^{b_1}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right|=\left|\int_{b_1}^{b_2}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right|\to0$$ as $b_1,b_2\to\infty$.

Comment: @philmcole: Just because a sequence is bounded, does not mean it converges.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks! But then we don't really need $(2)$ and $(3)$ anymore, when we can just show this because we then know it converges by Cauchy.

Comment: @philmcole: Cauchy sequences are sequences. We are duplicating the idea since this is not a sequence.

Comment: How do you know that $g'$ is Riemann integrable over $[a, b]$, and if you don't claim it is, how do you know that $\int \limits_a^b F(x) g'(x) \, \mathrm{d} x$ exists?

Comment: @Adayah: If $g'$ is not Riemann integrable, then $\int_a^bF(x)g'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ should be replaced by the [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Properties): $\int_a^bF(x)\,\mathrm{d}g(x)$. Each of the estimates above are valid with this replacement.

Comment: Can I ask, f(x) is not continuous, so how does this integration by parts formula hold?

Comment: @alan23273850: take $f=v'$ and $g=u$ in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Validity_for_less_smooth_functions).