# Does $f(x)\in L^1$ imply that $f'(x) \in L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f(x)$ be [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function#Formal_definition) for all real numbers [differentiable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function) function of one variable.We know that:
$$\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty } |f(x)| \, dx\neq +\infty$$
Problem is to resolve if it is possible or not that:
$$\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty } |f'(x)| \, dx= +\infty$$

Comment: What do you expect, will the derivative always be integrable or not?

Comment: Try playing around with $x^2\sin(1/x^2)$. (Maybe not the best approach.)

Comment: Try $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\sin(x^6)$.

Comment: @DavidMitra that takes care of Riemann integrability, but what about Lebesgue?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom oopsie... will delete.

Comment: @Etienne $$\lim_{X\to +\infty } \, \int_X^{X+1} f'(x) \, dx=0$$

Comment: @DavidMitra $$\int_1^{+\infty}x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \, dx=\int_{-\infty}^{-1} x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \, dx = +\infty$$

Comment: I said "play" with it. Obviously, you'll want to redefine the tails.

Comment: @DavidMitra It doesn't belong to $L^1$.

Comment: @Darius: Start with David's idea, and make some changes, then get your counterexample.  YOU should do the work, not David!  That way, you may learn something.

Comment: @Darius The fact that $\int_X^{X+1} f'(x)dx\to 0$ as $X\to\infty$ does not imply that $f'$ is integrable. Actually, it is not...

Comment: @Etienne Note that in your example: $$\varepsilon :\forall_{ x \in <X,X+\varepsilon>} (f'(x) \geqslant 0)  \underline\vee (f'(x) \leqslant 0) \implies \lim_{X\to \infty } \, \int_X^{\varepsilon+X} f'(x) \, dx=0$$ but $$\exists_{x_n:\lim \, x_n=+\infty } \lim \, f'(x_n)=+\infty$$ furthermore $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f'(x) \, dx=0$, what induces further analysis. 

btw.: Do you know if it is possible that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |h(x)| \, dx\neq +\infty$ when $\exists_{x_n:\lim \, x_n=+\infty } \lim \, |h(x_n)|=+\infty$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that trying to use a "single formula function" makes things unnecessarily complicated. Here is a counterexample. It is based on the function
$$
t\mapsto (x-a)^2(b-x)^2.
$$
This function, on the interval $[a,b]$ is differentiable with both the function and the derivative being zero at the endpoints. Such a feature allows us to put these "lumps" in different places and still get a differentiable function. Let
$$
f(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^8(x-n)^2(n+\frac1{n^2}-x)^2\,1_{[n,n+\frac1{n^2}]}.
$$
As $n$ grows, the lumps are thinner and higher. So we can get small areas with big derivatives:
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} |f|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1/n^2}n^8(x-n)^2(n+\frac1{n^2}-x)^2
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,n^8\,\frac1{30n^{10}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{30n^2}<\infty.
$$
And
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}|f'|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1/n^2}|2n^8(x-n)(n+1/n^2-x)(2n+1/n^2-2x)|\,dx\\
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1/2n^2}2n^8(x-n)(n+1/n^2-x)(2n+1/n^2-2x)\,dx\\-\int_{n+1/2n^2}^{n+1/n^2}2n^8(x-n)(n+1/n^2-x)(2n+1/n^2-2x)\,dx\\
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^8\,\frac1{8n^8}=\infty
$$

Comment: It looks like created by human , who is counting six-digit numbers products just in his memory.

Answer (score 2):

**Counterexample:** take 
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^2e^{-x^2}\sin(1/x^2) & x \neq 0\\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
Note that although $f$ is absolutely integrable,
$$
f'(x) = \begin{cases}
2e^{-x^2}\frac{x^2(x^2 - 1)\sin(1/x^2) + \cos(1/x^2)}{x}
& x \neq 0\\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
Is not.

In this way, I have used the function $e^{-x^2}$ to "play" with David's function and "redefine the tails".

---

Proof that $f'(x)$ is not absolutely integrable:

Note that $|f'(x)| \geq C \left|\frac{\cos(1/x^2)}{x}\right|$ for some constant $C$.   It is thus sufficient to show that the integral
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \left|\frac{\cos(1/x^2)}{x}\right| \,dx
$$
Diverges.  To show that this is the case, note that
$$
\int^{1/\sqrt{\pi n}}_{1/\sqrt{\pi(n+1)}} \left|\frac{\cos(1/x^2)}{x}\right| \,dx \\ \geq
\int^{1/\sqrt{\pi(n+1/4)}}_{1/\sqrt{\pi(n+3/4)}} \left|\frac{\cos(1/x^2)}{x}\right| \,dx \\ \geq
\left(\frac 1{\sqrt{(n + 1/4)\pi}} - \frac 1{\sqrt{(n + 3/4)\pi}}\right)\cdot \sqrt{n \pi} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
$$
Show that this is bounded below by $D/n$ for some constant $D>0$.  From there, it follows that
$$
\int_{-1}^1 |f'(x)|\,dx \geq \sum_{n=-N}^N D/n
$$
From which we conclude that the integral diverges.

Comment: Nicer than what I actually meant (set the function to $0$ off $[-1,1]$ and "smooth it out" around $1$ and $-1$).

Comment: Ah, I suppose that works too.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Your counterexample is against assumption that $f(x)$ is defined for all real numbers and differentiable. Consider $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$

Comment: We can fix the condition for $f$ by redefining $f$ at $0$ as $f(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$.  Not sure about $f'(x)$ though.

Comment: In fact, this new $f$ is actually differentiable at $x = 0$.  Consider the fact that $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2 \sin(1/h^2) - 0}{h} = 0$$

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $$
h(x) = \begin{cases}
2e^{-x^2}\frac{x^2(x^2 - 1)\sin(1/x^2) + \cos(1/x^2)}{x}
& |x| \geq 1\\ 
0 & |x| < 1
\end{cases}
$$ is absolutely integrable. So I need some more clarifications.

Comment: That's not $f'(x)$.  The function $f'(x)$, which is indeed what I've said it is, is not absolutely integrable between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Can you prove that, if $$
f'(x) = \begin{cases}
2e^{-x^2}\frac{x^2(x^2 - 1)\sin(1/x^2) + \cos(1/x^2)}{x}
& x \neq 0\\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$ then $$\int_{-1}^1 |f'(x)| \, dx= +\infty$$ ?

Comment: I've sketched a proof in my answer

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Note that if $0.465<x<0.47$ then $f'(x)$ is changing its sign, but $\frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x}$ not , and its absolute value is not zero. That means that assumption about some positive constant $C$ is wrong.

Comment: Fine.  Note instead that $$|f'(x)| \geq B|x^2(x^2-1)\sin(x)/x| + C|\cos(1/x^2)/x|$$ for some constants $B$ and $C$, and that $|x^2(x^2-1)\sin(x)/x|$ is absolutely integrable.  We reach the conclusion, once more, that $f'$ is absolutely integrable only if $|\cos(1/x^2)/x|$ is absolutely integrable, which it is not.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I am still not sure your solution.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo there.  I am bounding the integral by the length multiplied by the minimum value of the integrand.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Note that: $$\int_{1/\sqrt{2 \pi +0.75\pi}}^{1/\sqrt{2 \pi +0.25\pi}} \left|\frac{\cos \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x}\right| \, dx\approx 0.03747674 <\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi +0.25\pi}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi +0.75\pi}}\right)\sqrt{2 \pi }\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}>0.06$$ It means that your inequality isn't kept when $n=2$. Besides minimum value of the integrand is $0$ when $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi(n+2/4)}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: $f(x)=\frac{\sin(e^x)}{1+x^2}$ - [smooth function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_function)
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left|\frac{\sin(e^x)}{1+x^2}\right| \,dx\leqslant \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2} \,dx=\pi$$

Which means that $f(x)\in L^1$
$$f'(x)=\frac{e^x \left(x^2+1\right) \cos \left(e^x\right)-2 x \sin \left(e^x\right)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}$$
Note: $\forall_{\varepsilon > 0} \lim_{X\to \infty } \, \int_X^{X+\varepsilon} f'(x) \, dx=0$
$$|f'(x)|=\frac{e^x \left(x^2+1\right) \left|\cos \left(e^x\right)-\frac{2 x}{x^2+1} \frac{\sin \left(e^x\right)}{e^x}\right|}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}\geqslant \frac{1}{2}\frac{e^x \left|\cos \left(e^x\right)-\frac{2 x}{x^2+1} \frac{\sin \left(e^x\right)}{e^x}\right|}{\left(x^2+1\right)}\geqslant \frac{1}{4}\frac{e^x \left(\cos \left(e^x\right)-\frac{2 x}{x^2+1} \frac{\sin \left(e^x\right)}{e^x}\right)^2}{\left(x^2+1\right)}$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f'(x)| \,dx > \frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^x \left(\cos \left(e^x\right)-\frac{2 x}{x^2+1} \frac{\sin \left(e^x\right)}{e^x}\right)^2}{\left(x^2+1\right)} \,dx$$

$\left|\frac{2 x}{x^2+1} \sin \left(e^x\right)\right|\leqslant 1$ which means that if we prove divergence of $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^x \cos \left(e^x\right)^2}{\left(x^2+1\right)} \,dx$ we prove divergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f'(x)| \,dx$.  $$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{e^x \cos \left(e^x\right)^2}{\left(x^2+1\right)} \,dx> \int_0^{+\infty}\cos \left(e^x\right)^2 \,dx=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2} \,dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{+\infty}\cos \left(2e^x\right) \,dx$$

Note that:$\left(\frac{e^x}{x^2+1}\right)^{'}=\frac{e^x (-1+x)^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}\geqslant 0$, so finally if $\int_0^{+\infty}\cos \left(2e^x\right) \,dx$ is convergent than $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f'(x)| \,dx=+\infty$.
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\cos \left(2e^x\right) \,dx=\int_2^{+\infty}\frac{\cos \left(v\right)}{v} \,dv$$
$\int_2^{+\infty}\frac{\cos \left(v\right)}{v} \,dv$ is convergent by [Dirichlet's test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413950/proving-abel-dirichlets-test-for-convergence-of-improper-integrals-using-integr) or even [Leibniz test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_test) with $a_n=\int_{n\pi+0.5\pi}^{(n+1)\pi+0.5\pi}\left|\frac{\cos \left(v\right)}{v}\right| \,dv$ , which completes the proof.

Comment: Nice proof. You could do the same with $\frac1{1+x^2}\sin(x^6)$.

Comment: @Etienne Yes indeed, $$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\cos(x^6)^2 \,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{+\infty} \,dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\cos(2 x^6) \,dx$$ $$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\cos(2 x^6) \,dx=\frac{1}{6\sqrt[6]{2}}\int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(v)}{v^{\frac{5}{6}}} \,dv$$ $$\int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(v)}{v^{\frac{5}{6}}} \,dv=\frac{-\sqrt[6]{2}\sin(2)}{2}+\frac{5}{6}\int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(v) \sqrt[6]{v}}{v^2} \,dv\approx -0.486261$$ $$\left(\frac{6 x^5}{(1 + x^2)^2}\right)^{'}=\frac{6 x^4 \left(5+x^2\right)}{\left(1+x^2\right)^3}\geqslant 0$$