# Statement of Abel's test and Dirichlet's test for bounded intervals

Tags: integration

I know both Abel's and Dirichlet's test for convergence of some integrals when the range of the integral is of the form $[a,\infty)$, $a > 0$ (the statement of Abel's test canbe found in [Proving Abel-Dirichlet's test for convergence of improper integrals using Integration by parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413950/proving-abel-dirichlets-test-for-convergence-of-improper-integrals-using-integr)). Is there any similar test for convergence of integrals by the name of Abel and Dirichlet when the range is a bounded interval of the form $[a,b]$, $0 < a < b$? i.e. want to conclude about the integrals of the form $\int_a^{b} f(x) * g(x)dx$.

Any reference or any kind of further help is highly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I did an edit. Kindly avoid exclamation marks in your titles.

Comment: Thanks. I shall remember that.