# Integral of $f(x)$ converges but of $f(x)^2$ diverges?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Does anybody know a function  $f$ **that is continuous on $[0, \infty)$**, so that $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converges but $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)^2dx$ diverges? Thanks

EDIT: Sorry! I meant that $f$ is also continuous there.

Comment: What do you mean by 
"the integral of $f$ converges"?

Comment: @zhw. It's in the post: $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ converges (i.e. exists, of course).

Comment: @arctictern But in what sense? Lebesgue, or as a Riemann improper integral?

Comment: Riemann improper

Answer (score 4):

A simple function with this property is $f(x)=\sin(x)/\sqrt{x}$, whose graph looks like so:

[image]

A simple appeal to the alternating series test shows that the integral converges, as
$$\int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} f(x) dx.$$

To see that the integral of $f(x)^2$ diverges, let's take a look at a graph of $f(x)^2$:

[image]

Each dashed rectangle that you see lives over an interval of the form
$[k\,\pi+\pi/6,k\,\pi+5\pi/6]$, which has length $4\pi/6$ or $2\pi/3$. The height of each rectangle is 
$$\frac{\sin^2(k\,\pi+5\pi/6)}{k\,\pi+5\pi/6} = \frac{1/4}{k\,\pi+5\pi/6}.$$

Thus, the sum total of the areas of those rectangles is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\pi/6}{k\,\pi+5\pi/6} = \infty.$$

As those rectangles lie wholly under the graph of the squared function, the improper integral must diverge as well.

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to add a simple method to prove this: use the Dirichlet convergence test for $f(x)$, then the comparison test for non-negatives with $1/x$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that [the following integral converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105107/prove-int-0-infty-sin-x2-dx-converges), and to the particular value.

$$\int_0^\infty\sin(x^2+2x+1)dx\approx3.16389$$

On the other hand,

$$\int_0^\infty\sin^2(x^2+2x+1)dx$$

does not converge.

Comment: What's wrong with this?  It satisfies all the given conditions as far as I can tell.

Comment: My upvote should make up for it. I guess someone felt that your answer could be more detailed, or maybe it was just some random downvoter.

Comment: I upvoted this.. But I can't understand how you got to this answer.

Comment: @Ron It would appear that this answer was obtained with a numerical integrator. The idea behind this answer, as with mine, is to relate the integral to an alternating series. In this case, the graph looks like [this](https://goo.gl/0bEOwA). The area of each portion over an interval the form $[\sqrt{k\pi}-1,\sqrt{(k+1)\pi}-1]$ is smaller than the previous area in absolute value because their width narrows as $k$ increases. The alternating sign of the sine yields convergence. The squared function is *not* alternating and the widths still decrease to zero harmonically yielding divergence.

Comment: @Ron Please see the link I provided on this famous integral.

Comment: @MarkMcClure WolframAlpha gave me a sort of closed form, though I couldn't imagine it being any good to post here.

Comment: @SimpleArt If you [compute the integral](https://goo.gl/W5xrdM) over an interval of the form $[\sqrt{k\pi}-1,\sqrt{(k+1)\pi}-1]$, you still get a result in terms of Fresnel's special function, but it's easy to see that the sum is collapsing showing convergence.

Answer (score 1):

We can find a  continuous function $f$ with values in $[0, \infty)$ that satisfies the condition. Indeed, consider a function that:

on every  interval of $[n,n+1]$ takes the value $n$ on an interval of length $1/n^3$ centered at $n+\frac{1}{2}$ and decreases to $0$ outside the central subinterval of length $\frac{2}{n^3}$. Then

$$\int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx \le 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^3} < \infty$$
but
$$\int_0^{\infty)} f^2(x) dx \ge \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{n^3} = \infty$$

In a similar way (say with subintervals of length $\frac{1}{n^2 \log^2 n}$, $n\ge 2$, and values $n$) we find $f\ge 0$ continuous on $[0, \infty)$ such that
$\int_{0}^\infty f(x) d x < \infty$, but $\int_0^{\infty}  f^s(x) dx = \infty$ for all $s> 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Take the function $f$ whose restriction to $[n,n+1[$ is the constant function $(-1)^{n+1}{1\over\sqrt {n+1}}$. It converges, but not $f^2$.

If you want $f$ to be continue, you can find $f_n:[n,n+1]$ such that $f_n(n)=f_{n+1}(n+1)=0$, $f_n\geq 0$ if $n$ is odd, $f_n\leq 0$ if $n$ is even and $\int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx=(-1)^{n+1}{1\over\sqrt {n+1}}$ by using bump functions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function

Comment: Sorry, forgot to write $f$ is continuous there.

Answer (score -1):

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the following? From @MarkMcClure's comment, there must be something wrong. It could must be a subtle point of improper Riemann integrals.

If $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and $\int_0^\infty f < \infty$, then $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, so there's some sufficiently large $R$ such that $f(x) \leq 1$ for $x > R$. Then $\int_R^\infty f^2 \leq \int_R^\infty f$; in particular, $\int_R^\infty f^2 < \infty$ (it exists). Since $f^2$ is the composition of continuous functions and $[0,R]$ is compact, $\int_0^R f^2$ also exists. Hence $\int_0^\infty f^2$ doesn't diverge.

Comment: That the limit as $x \to \infty$ of $f$ is 0 need not be true. You can take triangular hats that get taller and taller but thinner and thinner, spaced out in a way such that they belong in $L^1$ but not in $L^2$

Comment: Also $\int f < \infty$ doesn't convey anthing, unless $f\ge 0.$