# Find two continuous functions such that $\int_1^\infty f(x) dx$ and $\int_1^\infty g(x) dx$ converge but $\int_1^\infty f(x)g(x) dx$ diverge

Tags: calculus

Since $\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx$ and $\int_1^\infty g(x) \,dx$ are converge,
$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$, so $f,g$ are fractional function, and denominator is changing more fast than numerator.

The product of two functions has the same situation
(i.e. denominator is changing more fast than numerator)

So how can we find such functions?

Comment: Some important things, it is not true that those limits are zero. If they exist, they are, but they need not exist. Worse, they certainly need not be fractional functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integral of $f(x)$ converges but of $f(x)^2$ diverges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022062/integral-of-fx-converges-but-of-fx2-diverges)

Answer (score 6):

Let $f(x)=g(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt x}$.  Then, clearly we see that $\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx=\int_1^\infty g(x)\,dx$ are convergent.

But, $\int_1^\infty f(x)g(x)\,dx=\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}\,dx$ diverges.

Answer (score 3):

If you have hard time finding problems near $\infty$, find them near $1$. Take $f=g$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}} $ for $x \in (1,2]$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 - 3}$ for $x \in (2,+\infty)$. Clearly $f$ is continuous and the integral is convergent, but $fg$ near $1$ is of form $\frac{1}{x-1}$, which will diverge.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest example  is perhaps $f(x)=g(x)=\frac 1 {\sqrt {x-1}}$. (Unless you want the functions defined and continuous at $1$ also).