# Find an example of functions $\int _1^{\infty }f(x)dx$ and $\int _1^{\infty }g(x)dx$ which converge, but $\int _1^{\infty }f(x)g(x)dx$ diverges

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I was going over some practice questions for an upcoming calculus exam and I came across this question: "Give an example of two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $\int _1^{\infty }f(x)dx$ and $\int _1^{\infty }g(x)dx$ both converge respectively, but $\int _1^{\infty }f(x)g(x)dx$ diverges." I am having a very difficult time with this question and cannot find a good answer. I've tried with polynomials, trigonometric functions, and exponential functions with no avail.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3329279/42969.

Comment: The functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ can have bumps in their graphs as $x \to +\infty$ that are high but at the same time narrow enough that they don't prevent $\int f$ and $\int g$ from converging. If you pick the bumps in $f$ and in $g$  to be in the same places, then on multiplying $f$ and $g$ they may become so high that now $\int fg$ doesn'r converge.

Comment: The question doesn't required boundedness of the functions.  Let $f(x)=g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$ for $1\le x\le 2$ and $=0$ otherwise.

Comment: For example, let $f=g=\sin(x)/\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: $\sin(x^2)$ definitely works by itself. $\int_0^{\infty}\sin^2(x^2)$ does not converge

Answer (score 1):

Set f(x) = g(x) such that they are $n^2$ on each interval $[n,n + 1/n^{4}]$ and zero otherwise.

Comment: Did you read [How to write a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)?